# How to find run-time errors before they happen?

Tags: vba, runtime-error

Is there any place that lists most (all would be ideal but unlikely) of the run-time errors that can happen for each function/statement/etc of VBA?

For example, the [FreeFile function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function) can throw `Run-time error '67': Too many files` but it's not stated in the documentation page.

So unless you already know the error, either you have a generic error handler that catches it and attempts to take care of it the best it can or it will be thrown to the user.

But if you were aware of it while programming you could attempt to use the optional argument as 1 (default 0) to change the range from 1-255 to 256-512, and if that didn't solved it, warn the user that too many files are being used and ask if it could [close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/close-statement) the last one to make space.

Some of those errors can go undetected for long periods of time until they are 
discovered unlike compile/syntax errors.

Searching for "VBA FreeFile run-time errors" does show that specific error eventually in some pages from people that ran into them but I'm looking for somewhere that lists the different errors more extensively.

Summing up, I want to be able to turn [unexpected errors into expected errors](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#Expected_Versus_Unexpected_Errors).

Comment: I've never seen (or needed) a complete list.  Instead I use F1 in the VBA IDE.  Place the cursor on a keyword and press F1.  This will bring up the MS help page for that particular keyword.  This should be your start for understanding what issues you may have to catch when using that keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Freeflow, I wasn't aware that you could do that. Though the question is more about preventing and being aware of possible errors rather than understanding and fixing them after they happen (to an user and not in the tests done while programming that may overlook it).

Answer (score 0):

This meant to be a comment but was getting very long.

I don’t have a URL to share which lists all possible VBA exceptions, but I believe error handling goes hand in hand with experience.

Obviously, some errors need common sense to prevent, for example, if you try to access a property of an object without checking for Null, you might get a Null Reference exception.

However, if you don’t have an experienced developer on your side to guide you, you will gain experience sometimes the hard way.

Indeed you need to try and catch as many specific exceptions as possible, but truth is, you cannot think of everything. Sometimes you will miss something due to poor documentation, or simply by been unaware of the problem. Therefore, I think you need to start with a generic error handler and as your application matures, the error handling matures as well by enhancing it with errors occurred during the lifetime of the application.

Good luck.